# Very low FPS on Chromium with Runescape

Tags: 11.10, java, chromium, games

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, and I am having trouble with Runescape, an in-browser Java game.

My fps used to be 40-50 when I would play on Windows, but now, on Ubuntu I'm at 4-5 fps. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

I use Chromium, and have installed Java 1.7.0_03

Comment: browser and java version?...

Comment: I'm in Chromium, Java 1.7.0_03.

If I run it in the Unix Client that is based off of the Windows client, that uses Java 1.6. It too runs at the same low fps.

Comment: Have you read this? http://services.runescape.com/m=forum/forums.ws?25,26,99,61985129

Comment: I've browsed this forum a few times (that's where I found the client, haha). What exactly should I be looking for?

Comment: @RyanMcClure if you want to notify another user please use @ and name of that user, so he will get notification and will be able to answer you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue with java7/openjdk7 is that they have linking issues with their own libraries so adding them into LD_LIBRARY_PATH should get you out of safemode :)

here is an example command using firefox and openjdk7

32bit:
    `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386 firefox`

64bit:
    `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64 firefox`

It works for the unix client and once the public testing is done (to see if this causes any other issues) i will make an automated script to fix it :)

Comment: Hey @HikariKnight! (By the way--LOVE the Unix client!!!) So, I just run the command in terminal and it works for the client as well as other browsers, or just Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

sadly after some proper testing the above do not work :(
however there are solutions provided in the runescape.com wiki
just search for Linux Known Issues and you will find the article

http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Linux_Known_Issues

And the fix i provided above (which do not work for the browsers, only client or java directly sadly) is integrated in the version 3.0 of the unix client, glad to hear you like it ryan :)